# Error while running gnome-terminal

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and my gnome-terminal does not work (I cannot do "run from terminal"). I have xterm, and when I try to run:

```
gnome-terminal
```

I get:

```
Traceback:
   File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
     from gi.repository import Glib, Gio
ModlueNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

I tried to reinstall:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

but it did not help.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you do anything with default python?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, I replaced python 3.5 with python 3.8

Answer (score 3):

Install the `python gi` module since it seems to be missing.

```
sudo apt install python-gi python3-gi
```